# Rails & Mysql / Postgresql : How to store product atributes in a database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, attributes, entity-attribute-value

I am looking to store product attributes in rails but I don't know what will be the best way to go about doing so dynamically.
I have considered using the EAV model or hashing the results in the database but I am unsure of the effectiveness of each and I was hoping I could gain more insight into how to accomplish this.

Basically with the Entity Attribute Value model the problem I have is that in the attribute value table how would I go about storing a plethora of different types of data eg(text, file, BLOB, varchar, integer, boolean .etc) provided that the columns in the attribute value table are defined as only a single data type.
eg the value table if set to **integer** won't support **BLOB**s

How do I get around this issue and if I have completely gone in the wrong direction how would I create a product attributes model?

Additionally, I have read that Magento is moving away from the EAV model for maintenance issues and that essentially it is really hard to implement effectively.

Then there are numerous problems with hashing the first being that if you hash a series of values to a database and then save them there cant be an addition to the series of values eg
if you insert the following into the table as product 1's value

```
{"name"=>"Bob"}
```

and then decide to update the attributes to include ie description before updating adding another product 2

```
{"name"=>"Bob", "description"=>"this is a description"}
```

product 1 will not have a description within the hash.

So now that I have explained what I have done to try and resolve this I will conclude with my question.
What is the most efficient and effective way to implement product attributes in a Ruby on Rails app?